# jquery nth-child select in a list with childern

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select an item from a nested list with jquery but I cannot do it so far

This is what I've tried so far

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target= ("div>ul>li>ol>li:nth-child(4)");
    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

And this is my html code:

```
  <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li> <--- This is what I am trying to access
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>something else</li>
            <li>something else</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target= $("div>ul>li>ol>li:nth-child(4)");
    // or var $target= $("div>ul>li>ol>li:last-child");
    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

You forgot the $

http://jsbin.com/asazey/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of your `$target.fadeOut('fast');`:

```
$($target).fadeOut('fast');
```

You're trying to use a jQuery method on a non-jQuery object.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q8mb6/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I tried Jonathan's answer and it worked.

Instead I add ":nth-child(1)" before the first "li" to make target more precise (i guess).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target = $("div>ul>li:nth-child(1)>ol>li:nth-child(4)");
    $target.fadeOut('fast');
});
```